# Android activity lifecycle when calling other activity on google glass

Tags: android, android-activity, google-glass, activity-lifecycle

I got a question about the activity lifecycle.

Let's say my activity calls the native camera activity. Then the methods onPause and onDestroy of my activity are called right? And when the camera activity has finished its task and my own activity is visible again then onResume and onRestart are called. Is this correct?

In my application onPause, onDestroy and onRestart are not called, onResume is only called when the application is started.
Could it be that the behaviour of activities is different on google glass, or is my expectation of the activity behaviour on android wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Android Life Cycle documentation, when some other app gets over the current activity (in your case its your activity) onStop will be called first. Your app will go in the background, onDestroy() would only be called when Android OS kills your app. onRestart should be called when reverting back to your app if the camera app is called as a part of an implicit_intent. So onPause and onDestroy wont be called in regular cases, onRestart would be called only if called explicitly.